# Как выбрать текст без тега?

Tags: парсер, simple-html-dom

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как, используя PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, выделить блоки "2009 Dodge Journey" и "2010 Dodge Journey":

```
<h1>
  2009 Dodge Journey
  <span class="ad-id">ID 1139495366</span>
  2010 Dodge Journey
  <span class="ad-id">ID 1139474783</span>
</h1>
```

У меня либо весь текст выбирается "2009 Dodge Journey ID 1139495366"... Либо со `<span>` тегом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С объектом htmlDOM можно работать как с обычным объектом, по этому просто удаляем ненужную информацию, и вытаскиваем оставшийся текст.

```
$html->find("h1", 0)->find('span', 0)->innertext = '';
$html->find("h1", 0)->plaintext;
```